# hr has a pointed end... How to get rid of this?

Tags: html, css

So I was looking at the page for horizontal lines [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_hr_default_css) and the horizontal line looked at bit weird at the beginning. I'm running windows with the chrome browser and I zoomed in to 500% view and I saw this: [image: Error]
Looking at the horizontal line you can make out a small dot at the beginning of the line that looks very annoying. Any ideas how to get rid of this?

Comment: I'm not sure about what happens. Could help if you post your code. An option trying to avoid that behavior could be creating a `<div>` with a style `height: 1px; width:90%;` (the same size of your `<hr>`) and set the ` border: 0.5px solid black;`

Comment: Chrome does show this dot, but I don't see it in FF. Maybe a render issue?

Comment: You can always manhandle it with CSS: `hr {display:block; height:1px;   border:0; border-top:1px solid #cccccc; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `hr` have inset borders:

[image]

The small dot you are seeing is the left border, which is as dark as the top border.

Then, you can just remove the left border.

[image]

```css
hr { 
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the border style to something like `border-style: solid`

```
hr { 
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```